# counting some string values for each group of id numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have data in this form:

```
import pandas as pd
people_num=[1,1,2,2,2]
visited_places=['school', 'restaurant', 'church', 'restaurant', 'church']

df= pd.DataFrame({'people_num':people_num, 'visited_places':visited_places})
```

I want to add a new column that contains the counting number of strings for each people number.

To visualize, Original table is like,

```
+------------+----------------+
| people_num | visited_places |
+------------+----------------+
|          1 | school         |
|          1 | restaurant     |
|          2 | church         |
|          2 | restaurant     |
|          2 | church         |
+------------+----------------+
```

And The new table I want to get from this :

```
+------------+------------------------------+
| people_num |       counts_of_places       |
+------------+------------------------------+
|          1 | {'school':1,'restaurant':1}  |
|          2 | {'church':2, 'restaurant':1} |
+------------+------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should put dictionaries into DataFrame columns.

I propose the following alternative solution.

```
>>> df
   people_num visited_places
0           1         school
1           1     restaurant
2           2         church
3           2     restaurant
4           2         church
>>> df.groupby('people_num')['visited_places'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
visited_places  church  restaurant  school
people_num                                
1                    0           1       1
2                    2           1       0
```

***... but if you insist***

```
>>> df.groupby('people_num')['visited_places'].agg(lambda g: g.value_counts().to_dict())
people_num
1    {'restaurant': 1, 'school': 1}
2    {'church': 2, 'restaurant': 1}
Name: visited_places, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ah! Your alternative solution sounds much better. I will make it even easier to sum up the number of visited places for a 'group of people' who has same values in other column! Thanks you so much again!

Comment: You can just pass `fill_value` to `.unstack` here, so you avoid the `fillna` and keep stuff as `int`s (if desirable), eg: `df.groupby('people_num')['visited_places'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)`